# Button to post image to Google+

Tags: google-plus

I know you can easily share a URL to a google plus page with just a simple link:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/PAGE_ID/share?url=http://example.com">Share To Google+</a>
```

But how would I go about doing this with an image so that it actually displays it as an image on Google+, not a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to share a URL and have it appear with an image on Google+ is to include http://schema.org markup in the target page.  This assumes you control the target of the URL you are sharing.

Take a look at the bottom of this page for an example of how to add schema.org markup to a page:

http://schema.org/Book

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you cannot share an image (aka upload an image) to Google+ with any of the plugins.  Like [Lee said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687548/1354939), you can share a page and get it to pick up your image as a thumbnailk, but you're not going to get the full image uploaded.